# ignore newton Json's JsonProperty on the fly?

Tags: c#, json.net

We have some web API and some clients to consume the output.

One api return this:

```
public class InstrumentInfoV11 : InstrumentInfoBase
    {
        [JsonProperty("InstrumentType")]
        public string InstrumentTypeCode { get; set; }
    }
```

basically our API output property `InstrumentType` and we want our c# client to have a property called `InstrumentTypeCode` instead. `JsonProperty` did work and the c# property is populated.

However, when we try to output the result from the client:

```
 InstrumentInfoV11 response = await Client.InstrumentInfoAsync(theRequest);
 return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response, Formatting.Indented);
```

The property InstrumentTypeCode becomes InstrumentType again

```
{
    "InstrumentType": "X",
    ...
}
```

Is there a way to tell newton that when SerializeObject, it should ignore `JsonProperty("InstrumentType")` and when deSerializeObject, it should take it into consideration?

Comment: so you want to read *either* name, but only ever write `InstrumentType` ?

Comment: It is working fine to serialize and deserialize: https://dotnetfiddle.net/nFIKEq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually serializers want to be able to store and reload the same data, so if you *store* something as X, it wants to *read* it as X, otherwise the assumption is that it can't do the job of loading data *it wrote*.

However, you could perhaps have two properties - allow either to read, and only ever write one; i.e.

```cs
// the real property
public string InstrumentTypeCode { get; set; }

// conditional serialization
[Browsable(false)]
public bool ShouldSerializeInstrumentTypeCode() => false;

// shim property
[Browsable(false)]
public string InstrumentType {
    get => InstrumentTypeCode;
    set => InstrumentTypeCode = value;
}
```

Comment: fantastic, your answer is like 99% solving the problem and I only need to change some tiny bits.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Custom Contract Resolver for the purpose. For example,

```
public class IgnorePropertyNameContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {

        IList<JsonProperty> list = base.CreateProperties(type, memberSerialization);
        foreach (JsonProperty prop in list)
        {
            prop.PropertyName = prop.UnderlyingName;
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

You could use Deserialize using Json Property Name

```
var jsonResponse = "{'InstrumentType':'abc'}";
var instance = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<InstrumentInfoV11>(jsonResponse);
```

And Serialize ignoring the Json Property Name

```
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings{ContractResolver = new IgnorePropertyNameContractResolver()};
var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(instance,settings);
```

**Output**

```
{"InstrumentTypeCode":"abc"}
```